# Very basic drawing on a map

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, map-drawing

I have lat/lng, angle with North and a length of a polygone.
I want to draw the polygone on a map. Like in this figure:

[image: figure polygone]

And I want to adjust opacity of it in realtime.

Which GIS or Map viewer I gonna use for this purpose.
Sadly, I will use it without Internet.

Any opensource-related advice or sample application will be best for me. Java is really okay for integrating my existing app.

Will openstreetmap or google maps provide me these?

Comment: You said `Sadly, I will use it without Internet` so why asking for OpenStreetMap or Google Maps? You will need OpenLayers and a good jQuery skill.

Comment: You can not use google maps, because it is not legally. So the choise is openstreetmap. There are many GIS (for example ArcGIS...), GIS components (DevExpress...) or frameworks (if you want to display your map in browser - OpenLayers...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map is OpenStreetMap.

The GIS component is DevExpress http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfMap (if you don't want use browser)

Or JavaScript libraries: OpenLayers, Leaflet or another (if you create web application)

Comment: OpenStreetMap without internet implies 1) Import OSM data to PostGIS 2) Some map server (MapServer / Geoserver) to OpenLayers consumes.

Comment: I prefer mapnik, because this is the official software for OpenStreetMap. wmsproxy - for wms and wmts

Comment: Embedding python into java application? No thanks :)

Comment: I saw java application with embedding c#, c++ + qt, erlang ...

And, of course, you can use server software with default options (without programming).